# Listing the Icons/Glyphs used with a font and "content:'\value'"

Tags: html, css, svg, fonts, icons

I am editing a pre-existing site that makes use of icons/glyphs in a multitude of files like eot, svg, w0ff, ttf (I guess for various compatibility). It calls these with the use of the font and a CSS value like this:

```
font-family: icons_filename;
content: "\e601";
```

So how would I find a list of the different values of the icons called with "content"?

In other words, I am trying to see what is possible in an undocumented library of icons that don't necessarily have a good list of names.

I also don't understand how the value "\e601" is used or how to look that up in a file. This part of CSS is unfamiliar to me and I cannot find a good explanation for this as most icon tutorials only show how to use a documented library.

Thanks

Comment: what is the font-family?

Comment: it's WOFF, the "web open font format", not w0ff. And if your job is to maintain this for the future: a lot of things changed in web font land since 3 years ago, at this point in time you *only* need WOFF sources.  Unless you need IE8 and below support (which Microsoft doesn't even do anymore as of January 2016, it finally killed them off) in which case you need WOFF and EOT, and that's it. The rest just waste time and bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for UTF-8 characters. Icon fonts generally override the default font on this universal icon font if they exist. Here's a [link to where you can view them](http://www.utf8icons.com/).

Comment: By the way, most of these icon font libraries have great documentation already.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto what Chris already said, you should be able to track down which font icon library your template/theme is utilizing.  One of the most common examples of these would be  [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/).

From the link above, you'll have the ability to go through each icon and figure out which "unicode" to select.  For example, "fa-blind" (blind man walking icon) has a unicode of "f29d", which translates to "\f29d" when using it for the CSS property "content"

If your stylesheet is served in UTF-8, you can avoid the need for unicodes (f29d in our example), and directly copy/paste the icon should it be listed on a site for you (i.e, instead of "\f29d" in the content, it'll be the actual fa-blind icon glyph.  It'll show up as a blank square in your CSS document, but will render properly when you're on the webpage.)

I might've gone on too long here, but ultimately what you need to do is figure out which library of icons the site is utilizing.  We could easily figure it out for you if a link is provided.